# How do I use the text from my database to authenticate as usernames and passwords?

Tags: python, authentication

My userpass.txt is like this:

gabiel,bab

sabiel,pont

mabiel,blont

instead of using bonjovi as username, and isagod as password, how do I use the left column of the text file associated with the words on the right column of the text file to access? It's such basic code because I'm 15 and in school.

```
import time
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("UserPass.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

print("*"*50)
print("Authentication Database")
print("*"*50)

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE tblUserPass
(
    usernames TEXT,
    passwords TEXT,
    primary key (usernames)
)"""
               )
print("tblUserPass created in UserPass.db")

def readTextFile(userFile):
    numRecs = 0
    userDBRec = []
    userTextRec = userFile.readline()
    while userTextRec != "":
        numRecs += 1
        field = userTextRec.split(",")
        usernames = field[0]
        passwords = field[1]
        print(usernames, passwords)
        userDBRec.append(usernames)
        userDBRec.append(passwords)
        cursor.execute ("insert into tblUserPass VALUES (?,?)", userDBRec)
        conn.commit()

        userDBRec = []
        userTextRec = userFile.readline() 
    return numRecs

userFile = open("UserPass.txt", "r")
numRecs = readTextFile(userFile)
print("\n",numRecs, "records transferred")
userFile.close()

for rows in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tblUserPass'):
    print(rows[1])

username=input("enter user")
password=input("enter pass")

while username!='bonjovi' or password!='isagod':
    print("one of 'em incorrect")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("go again")
    username=input("ENTER USER AGAIN")
    password=input("ENTER PASS AGIAN")

print("hento and welcom")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should never store password as clear text in your database, [hash it then store it](https://zinoui.com/blog/storing-passwords-securely).

This is actually a simple db query,

```
username=input("enter user")
password=input("enter pass")

while cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM tblUserPass where usernames='{username}' AND passwords='{password}'").fetchone() is None:
    print("one of 'em incorrect")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("go again")
    username=input("ENTER USER AGAIN")
    password=input("ENTER PASS AGIAN")

print("hento and welcom")
```

the query is to search for the row which matches both username and password.

Finally, welcome to SO and bravo taking the initiative to write things from scratch.

EDIT

Prior of this, this is a small problem when you initialize your database, when you do `userTextRec = userFile.readline()` there is actually a newline character at the end, therefore all your password (except for the last line) is suffixed with `\n`. To remove it, do `field = userTextRec.split('\n')[0].split(",")`.

Comment: Thanks, homie. would you mind explaining the len, f, == 0 ?
Just tryna learn :)

Comment: @GabeSaban `len()` is a built-in function to count the number of elements in a list, `f""` is a feature in python3.6+ called f string: formatted string, == 0, well, means "is the value equal to 0?", you really should understand these basic functions/keywords before start programming.

Comment: i'm tr ying to learn, and there's no way to learn other than doing it, i'm not going to study all python commands before even trying, am i?

Comment: you are absolutely right but things like `if` and `len` should really be the things you learn first

Comment: yeah i know about if, but sql is something i'm not comfortable with

Comment: i'm being told this, please help: "TypeError: object of type 'sqlite3.Cursor' has no len()"

Comment: @GabeSaban my bad, see the updated answer, cursor with "SELECT" can be used as an iterator, so there is no len(), use fetchone(), https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, but it seems that the code is only now accepting mabiel as a username and blont as a password - i have tried it with fetchall() but now that's just accepting anything as a username and password